# Remove a register from a quantum circuit

Tags: qiskit

I am trying to make a function like this in Qiskit:

```
def some_function(qc: QuantumCircuit):
  # Add a register to qc
  qc.add_register(size, name)
  # Do some computation
  # Remove the register from qc
```

The first two tasks of adding a register and doing some computation on the qubits is okay. For the last part, i.e., removing the register, I couldn't find any resources on the web. The documentation for [QuantumCircuit](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit) didn't list anything as such to remove a register.

[This](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25672/remove-inactive-qubits-from-qiskit-circuit) discussion does give some idea of how to remove idle wires from a quantum circuit, but my problem is to remove only the specific qubits in the register that I am adding, not all the idle ones. Moreover, the register information is lost by following what the suggested answer gives, which I do not want.

[This](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5144/can-i-remove-gates-from-a-quantumcircuit) discussion gives the equivalent solution for Quantum Gates, not registers.

Is there a way to remove a register from a quantum circuit by name of register? Any help would definitely be appreciated!